# Filtering warnings in django tests

Tags: django, unit-testing

I'm trying to make some warnings thrown by django be raised as errors in my unit tests.

I've configured my test settings this way:

```
from warnings import filterwarnings
from django.core.paginator import UnorderedObjectListWarning

filterwarnings('error', category=UnorderedObjectListWarning)
```

When I run my test on one application, the warning is correctly raised as an exception.
But if I run my test globally, no exception is raised.

```
./manage.py test myapp  # warnings are raised as exception
./manage.py test  # no exception
```

Why do I have this difference and how can I manage to have warnings raised as exception when running all my tests ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```py
try:
    function_you_want_to_test()
except CustomException:
    self.assertTrue(False)  # This code is only executed if the CustomException is thrown.
```

Comment: This is not what I asked for. I want to check if my running code don't get any specifics from django, not testing some exception. And exceptions are better tested with the assertRaises method.